# How to update value inside an array from multiple array in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a `User` mongodb structure like below.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("54d2f68edbe2337d000e1568"),
"username" : "khayusaki@gmail.com",
"organization" : [ 
    {
        "idOrganization" : "54c8b01af927db992d021f58",
        "usertype" : 1,
        "displayname" : "K",
    },
    {
        "idOrganization" : "54c8b01af927db992d021f60",
        "usertype" : 2,
        "displayname" : "Khay",
    }
],
"__v" : 0
}
```

It means like a user can have many organizations, and each displayname and usertype depends on it. What I want to do is, I only want to update the `displayname` of one organization by using JSON from request body.

```
{
"Displayname" : "Khay Usaki",
"Email" : "khayusaki@gmail.com"
}
```

My mongoose query is like below.

```
User.findOne({username: req.body.Email},
            {organization: {$elemMatch: {idOrganization: '54c8b01af927db992d021f58'}}},     
                function(err, user) {
                    if (err) res.send(err);

                    user.organization[0].displayname = req.body.Displayname;
                    user.save();
                    res.json({'message' : 'User successfully updated'});
                }
});
```

If I add `console.log(user)` before `save()` function, it gives me what I want to.

```
{   
_id: 54d2f68edbe2337d000e1568,
organization: 
[ 
    { 
        idOrganization: '54c8b01af927db992d021f58',
        usertype: 1,
        displayname: 'Khay Usaki',
    } 
] 
}
```

But it really doesn't save.I wish there might be someone who could help me find a solution for it.

p.s. I tried with `$push` in `User.findOne` and it is also not working either.

=== Solution =====
Thanks @BatScream for the suggestion and it gets working as following.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({
    username: req.body.Email,
    organization: {$elemMatch: {idOrganization: "54c8b01af927db992d021f58"}}
},
{$set: {"organization.$.displayname": req.body.Displayname}}, {},
function(err, response) {
    // handle own response
});
```

Comment: The `elemMatch` is not required.

Comment: @BatScream It doesn't work when I used `"organization.idOrganization":"54c8b01af927db992d021f58"` like you asked me to. It showed me **MongoError* . So I had to try again with `$eleMatch` and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [**$**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) positional operator in the [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) method.

```
 Model.findOneAndUpdate({"username": req.body.Email,
         "organization.idOrganization":"54c8b01af927db992d021f58"},
         {$set:{"organization.$.displayname":req.body.Displayname}},
         {},
 function(err,resp){//handle response})
```

Comment: WoW! Thanks for your idea. I update the question with answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
user.organization.add(another_orginaztion);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but won't it add new organization in that users collection? I just want to update the `displayname` inside related organization. Don't want to add another array with the same `idOrganization` with different `displayname`. And also it is showing there has no method 'add'.